# error: unable to create file ....: Invalid argument

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, git

I recently passed Xubuntu from 16.04 to 20.04. A simple command like:

```
git pull
```

generates the following errors (all similar among them):

```
error: unable to create file Template/images/N<X.pdf: Invalid argument
...
```

I guess because there are special characters in some of the files (specifically the characters `<` and `>`). I had no problem with XUbutnu 16.04 and now I do not know how to download the file that I need. Any suggestion or walkaround is appreciated.

Comment: is this your repository? Can you login to git repository by web page and rename this file in repository ? Or maybe you can download from web page as .zip file?

Comment: git is completely agnostic concerning the DE/OS. I'd ask a git site, not at an OS site....

Comment: @kanehekili, git operate on an OS. Git asks the system to do something. The OS has an important impact on the action performed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097568/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-file-invalid-argument/26097902 . However, how I stated, the action was allowed on Xubuntu 16.04 and not in 20.04